# How to get error messages into the login modal

Tags: php

I have a login modal that is within the header of my website and appears on screen when the user clicks on the login button. Whenever i submit the login form it creates a new page with the errors placed on it. Instead of this i am looking for the errors to come up within the login modal. Anyone know how i could achieve this ?

This is login.php

```
<?php                       //checks pword and email match on database
// Check if the form has been submitted:
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

// Requires two additional files
require ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');
require ('C:\xampp\htdocs\final\includes\db.php');


// Check the login.
list ($check, $data) = check_login($dbc, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']);

if ($check) { // OK!

    // Set the session data.
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
    $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];



    // Redirect the customer to loggedin page
    redirect_user('loggedin.php');

  } else { // If unsuccessful

        // Assign $data to $errors for login_page.inc.php:
    $errors = $data;

  }

   mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

   }

    // Create the page:
     include ('includes/login_page.inc.php');
    ?>
```

this is login_page.inc

```
    <link href="css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<?php   //displays errors and creates form

    // Include the header:
    $page_title = 'Login';
        if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
                            echo '<h1><font color="orange">Error!</font>          </h1>
                            <p class="error">The following error(s)  occurred:<br />';
                            foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
                        }
                        echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';
                        }


    // Display the form
     ?>


        <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"   aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="loginmodal-container">
                <h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br>
              <form action="login.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
              </form>

            <div class="login-help">
                    <a>Dont have an account? - </a><a      href="register.php">Register</a> 
                  </div>
                  <?php
                  // Display error messages if there are any
                    /*  if (isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {
                            echo '<h1><font color="orange">Error!</font>    </h1>
                            <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
                        foreach ($errors as $msg) {
                        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
                        }
                        echo '</p><p>Please try again.</p>';
                        }
               */
              ?>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is login_functions.inc

```
 <?php                                  //checks for errors
function redirect_user ($page = 'index.php') {

    $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

    $url = rtrim($url, '/\\');

    $url .= '/' . $page;

    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Quit the script.

    }


    // Checks the validation of the login.
    function check_login($dbc, $email = '', $password = '') {

    $errors = array(); // Initialize error array.

    // Validate the email address:
    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
    } else {
        $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($email));
    }

    // Validate the password:
    if (empty($password)) {
        $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
    } else {
        $p = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($password));
    }

    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

        // Retrieve the customer_id and first_name for that email/password combination:
        $q = "SELECT id, first_name FROM user WHERE email='$e' AND password=SHA1('$p')";        
        $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); // Run the query.

        // Check the result:
        if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {

            // Fetch the record:
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            // Return true and the record:
            return array(true, $row);

        } else { // Not a match!
            $errors[] = 'The email address and password entered do not match those on file.';
        }

    } // End of empty($errors) IF.

    // Return false and the errors:
    return array(false, $errors);

    } // End of check_login() function.
```

Comment: That can only be achieved via AJAX.

Comment: any idea how to do it ?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve what you want. The easiest would be to have both the login and backend inside the same file making the errors only appear with if / else conditions. A more elegant way is through Ajax. But this is also quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: @davo4, yes I can help with the AJAX implementation.  But it'll change your code in no small way, are you ready for that too? And can you use Javascript, even if it is only JQuery?

Comment: yeah i have used jQuery before. anything to make it work really

Comment: ok. let me prepare some stuffs for you

Comment: If you dont want to use jQuery / AJAX, which you really should then just make it so if there's an error it redirects to the same page with an error GET variable and on the page within the modal use an IF statement to check if that variable exists and if it does echo out the error and then at the bottom within your JavaScript use the same IF statement to trigger the modal

Comment: @iJamesPHP, the challenge is that when the page refreshes, the modal fades away which is normal.

Comment: I've used this old fashion method many a time before and it's worked. Good answer below, thankyou please mark as answer @davo4

Comment: the answer below does not work ? the form is now showing at the top of my page and no modal is coming up. also when i click the login that is supposed to trigger the modal brings it to another page and there are no errors shown either

Comment: sorry .. got it sorted yeah it worked .. Thanks

Comment: Good. I was planning on commenting every bit of the AJAX script, but is good that you understands them.

Comment: the only problem is now that even if the user is in the database it is still saying that login not successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an AJAX solution.  Many changes to your file, but well commented.

In **login_page.inc** only the form is affected:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="email">
<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" id="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Login">
<div id="login_msg"></div>
```

Then replace your entire **login.php** with this code:

```
// Check if the form has been submitted:
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

// Requires two additional files
    require ('includes/login_functions.inc.php');
    require ('C:\xampp\htdocs\final\includes\db.php');


// Check the login.
    list ($check, $data) = check_login($dbc, $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass']); //you'll need to validate your email and password before inputing them into this method

    if ($check) { // OK!

        // Set the session data.
        session_start(); //this should be the first thing in your page, if possible in line 1
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        $_SESSION['first_name'] = $data['first_name'];



        die("true"); //stops here and send response to the AJAX Script
        //redirect_user('loggedin.php');

    } else { // If unsuccessful

        // Assign $data to $errors for login_page.inc.php:
        $errors = $data;

    }

    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

}

    // Create the page:
     include ('includes/login_page.inc.php');

}
```

Include JQuery into your project. Create a new file called **ajax.js**, and link it to your project too.  This is the content of ajax.js:

```
/*
* Login User
*/
$(".loginmodal-submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var login = $(".loginmodal-submit").val();

    if (email != "" && password != "") {

        $("login_msg").html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg text-success' style='font-size:20px'></i>");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "login.php",
            data: {login: login, email: email, password: password},
            success: function (response)
            {
                if (response == "true") {
                    $(".login-modal").html("<span class='alert alert-success'>Login successful! Redirecting...</span>");
                    window.location.href = "loggedin.php";
                }
                else {
                    $("#login_msg").html('Sorry, your registration was not successful. Please check your details and try again: ');
                    console.log(response)
                }

            }
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: the form is now showing at the top of my page and no modal is coming up. also when i click the login that is supposed to trigger the modal brings it to another page and there are no errors shown either

Comment: @davo4, 
 
I hope you didn't replace your entire login_page.inc with the one I sent. it is only the form area, you need to replace with mine. Pls confirm that this is what you did.